# Virtualenv setup returns ImportError

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv, python-3.5

I am trying to install tensorflow with virtualenv, but I get the following error when I run "virtualenv --system-site-packages tensorflow". I am currently working this on macOS with python3.5.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "~/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
download=download,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/tensorflow/bin/python3.5 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: This looks like an install problem. We like to track these on our github issue page. Please file an issue there.

Comment: @drpng https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7591

Comment: @drpng my issue is closed due to the fact it is nothing to do with tensorflow.